# import random - randint in python not working

Tags: python, python-import

I've been somehow chosen to do a python competition tomorrow (aio.edu.au) and I am attempting one of the practice questions and already failing because apparently random.randit needs a string.

I've tried this...

```py
import random
a = "7 2"
b = a.split(" ")
random.randint(0, b[0])
```

I expected it the output of, well, any number chosen RANDOMLY between 0 and 7, inclusive. But it gives this error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 4, in <module>
    random.randint(0, b[0])
  File "/opt/python-3.6/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 220, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Any help?

Comment: You sure the error is correct?

Comment: Yep. Just ran it myself for 3.6 and got the same. Looks like it might be the type checking in the `random._randbelow` function...

Comment: Yeah I am sure... but does this mean that randint won't work???

Comment: @DasGuyDatSucks It works fine, it's just a by-product of being an untyped language. See my answer below for an explanation of what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you split a string you get an array of strings, ranint won't take string as an argument so you have to convert it to integer.

```
import random
a = "7 2"
b = a.split(" ")
random.randint(0, int(b[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Congrats! You've found an uncaught exception in the `random` module!

`random.randint(a, b)` takes two integers as input (namely `a` and `b`, where `a` is less than or equal to `b`, [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)). But the error message is incorrect. It should read something like:

```py
TypeError: must be int, not str
```

So if your string value isn't needed as a part of your input, you can just drop in pure integers, or perhaps from a list, or you can keep the string input if you really need to:

```py
import random

# just a single integer
random.randint(0, 7)

# using a list of potential values
bounds = [7, 2]
random.randint(0, bounds[0])
random.randint(0, bounds[1])

# or stick with the string conversion
bounds = "7 2"
random.randint(0, int(bounds.split(" ")[0])
random.randint(0, int(bounds.split(" ")[1])
```

---

Edit: In case anyone is interest in the exception, here is the definition of `randint`:

```py
def randint(self, a, b):
    """Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.                                        
    """
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
```

The problem is `b+1` is `str + int`, which is why the `TypeError` appears as per the question.

Comment: I tried this in Python 3.7 and the error message is more clear: *TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str*

Comment: I'd argue that that's not clear in the slightest! Seems to suggest that `randint` can accept `str` args, when it should just be `int`. It's pretty poor that this wasn't caught before release. Its a pretty simple test.

Comment: Well, at least you see the problem clearly when you compare the message with the statement (on the stack trace) that causes it. Python is dynamically typed and you cannot expect the library to do explicit type checking everywhere (in this case, that only generates a different error message). That could lead to quite some overhead.

Comment: Wow! Thanks... helpful answer but I don't understand, I thought randint should work? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @DasGuyDatSucks it does work. you just need to make sure that the type of whatever you pass to the `randint` function is an `int` (integer type), e.g. `7` or `2`, not `”7”` or `”2”` (ie strings, or anything else).

Answer (score 0):

You have used `split` to convert string to a list of strings. They are not integers and randint takes integers.

Convert str to int:

```
>>> random.randint(0, int(b[0]))
4
>>>
```